# Get the time range that a Log backup covers

Tags: sql-server, database

We get the backup start and end times. We also get the start LSN and end LSN but do not have a time range that the log backup covers.

I went thru CDC functions to convert a LSN to a date time, but that will require the customer to enable CDC for databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.fn_dump_dblog()` to find the approximate time range covered by log backup:

```
select min([Begin Time]), max([Begin Time])
from sys.fn_dump_dblog (
        NULL, NULL, N'DISK', 1, N'full_path_to_log_backup_file.trn',
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT,
        DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Here you can find more on `sys.fn_dump_dblog()`:

[Using fn_dblog, fn_dump_dblog, and restoring with STOPBEFOREMARK to an LSN](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/using-fn_dblog-fn_dump_dblog-and-restoring-with-stopbeforemark-to-an-lsn/)